# Spring Security sem autenticação

Tags: java, spring

Tenho um sistema que já faz a autenticação do usuário, e controla o acesso à páginas que exige autenticação, preciso usar o spring security para controlar acesso as páginas por regras de usuário e para controlar acesso a determinados recursos, como por exemplo um usuário ter permissão apenas para listar registros e não ter para excluir registros.

Tentei implantar um login com spring securiy e passar a responsabilidade da autenticação para a minha a classe que cuida do login no sistema, fazendo uma implementação do UserDetailsService, mas não obtive sucesso.

Os tutorias que encontrei na web abordam a autenticação e dão pouca atenção para a autorização, alguém sabe de algum link interessante para a minha necessidade?

O meu código está assim:

web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<display-name>Ultracar Web</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<!--<context-param>
 <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
 <param-value>-1</param-value>
</context-param>
-->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Principal/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml            
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

spring-security:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="Principal/index*" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/Principal/*" access="permitAll"/>

    <form-login login-page="/Principal/index.xhtml"        
                         default-target-url="/"
                         authentication-failure-url="/"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/" />
</http>
```

pagina de login:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
```

```
<h:head>
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="../Imagens/logo.png"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="./../Principal/template_inicio.xhtml">            
        <ui:define name="content">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="container" style="padding: 10px;">
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-xs-9 col-sm-9">
                        <ui:include src="slider.xhtml"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3" style="padding: 17px 0;background-color: #B3B3B3;">
                        <img class="img-responsive" style="margin: 0 auto" src="#{request.contextPath}/Imagens/logo.png" />

                        <h:form id="frmLogin" class="form-group" >

                                <div class="row">                                    
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ">
                                        <h:outputLabel style="color: #303030;" value="#{Utils.getStrLanguage('Usuario')}:" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                        <p:inputText value="#{MBControl.login}" required="true"
                                                     style="width: 100%;-moz-box-shadow: none !important; -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; 
                                                     box-shadow: none !important; -moz-border-radius: 0 !important; 
                                                     -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important; border-radius: 0 !important;"
                                                     requiredMessage="#{Utils.getStrLanguage('Usuario_requerido')}"/>
                                    </div>                                    
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                        <h:outputLabel style="color: #303030;" value="#{Utils.getStrLanguage('Senha')}:" />
                                    </div>                                    
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                                        <p:password value="#{MBControl.senha}" required="true" id="txtSenha" styleClass="reset-style"
                                                    style="width: 100%;-moz-box-shadow: none !important; -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; 
                                                    box-shadow: none !important; -moz-border-radius: 0 !important; 
                                                    -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important; border-radius: 0 !important;"
                                                    requiredMessage="#{Utils.getStrLanguage('Senha_requerida')}"/>
                                    </div>                                   
                                </div>

                                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
                                        <p:commandLink id="btnLogin" styleClass="btn button-green" ajax="false" action="#{MBControl.logar()}" 
                                                       update="frmLogin" value="#{Utils.getStrLanguage('Login')}" style="border-radius: 0 !important;"/>
                                    </div>                                                     
                        </h:form>
                    </div>                        
                </div> 
            </div>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

Não sei como fazer o spring chamar minha classe de login, e depois como controlar as permissões através do spring.

Desde já agradeço á todos pela ajuda

Comment: Renan, vou acompanhar eu estou também com problemas com o [tag:spring-security] mas usando anotações e Servlet API 3.1

Comment: Ok, qualquer novidade eu te aviso.

Answer (score 1):

Salve!

Eu não vi na sua configuração onde você está declarando o `UserDetailsService` que você implementou no seu contexto do Spring. Imagino que você deve ter feito isso em outro arquivo de configuração?

É preciso declarar a sua implementação como um `bean` e depois adicioná-lo no `AuthenticationManager` que você está utilizando, que neste caso é o do formulário de login.

Adicione esse trecho na sua configuração e veja se funciona:

```
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref="ID_DO_BEAN_DA_SUA_IMPLEMENTACAO">
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Exemplo retirado [deste artigo](http://technirman.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/spring-security-custom-userdetails.html).

Sobre a autorização, sugiro você abordar com [Spring Security ACL](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html). Veja na documentação oficial como ele funciona. Há poucos exemplos na web, mas é possível entender o seu funcionamento utilizando o JavaDoc, os poucos artigos e a documentação oficial.

Uma vez configurado o ACL, você pode exercer o controle do acesso aos dados do seu domínio de acordo com o perfil do usuário da aplicação. Entretanto, reveja o design da aplicação para você lidar com esse método o menos possível.

O "ideal" seria se você controlasse o acesso dos usuários por meio dos *endpoints* da sua aplicação. Ex: `/admin` apenas ROLE_ADMIN, `/gerente` apenas ROLE_GERENTE. Claro que nem sempre isso é possível, como um combo que virá com itens que apenas o Gerente Nível 1 pode ver... mas tente focar na interação dos usuários e no fluxo das páginas da sua aplicação. Fica mais fácil dar manutenção no futuro.

Se ainda tiver dúvidas, poste nos comentários que eu tento responder.